# A practical design scenario using Row/RowLayout

Tags: qt, qml

Though there are some links on stack overflow that might already explained the difference between Row vs RowLayout, I want to ask about **a practical layout design scenario**:

Suppose there is a scalable screen scaling keeping its aspect ratio, the screen consists of different main parts which arranged on the screen using Row/Column or RowLayout/ColumnLayout, I call these item positioners the **1st Level Item Positioner**. Each main part has its own child parts which are also arranged inside those main parts using Row/Column or RowLayout/ColumnLayout, I call these positioners the **2nd Level Item Positioner**.

My idea is to use RowLayout/ColumnLayout instead of Row/Column in the 1st Level since they can make their child elements(main parts)re-sizable, while to use Row/Column in the 2nd level positioner since it saves performance. Though there maybe some other practical issues leading to a mixture of both(like there will be no Layout only or Row/Column only usage, there will be sth which is mixture of both), **my general idea is to use Layout in the overall item positioning and arrangement while to use Row/Column in each child part. Basically try to use as many Row/Column as possible, use Layout only when Row/Column can't meet requirements like re-sizable** Is my idea alright? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried your idea? If you did, you could experiment and maybe you would answer yourself

Comment: It worked somehow, but I don't know that was the best approach, as you know in QML programming multiple ways can always work but there is just one best, most elegant way

Comment: The concept of best approach is very relative, if you do not point out how to measure some characteristic, but only it is subjective, in general what works is used. The elegant has a touch of subjectivity but this leads to seek simplicity, reusability, etc. How that depends on the specific case and not on a generalization

Comment: You say: *while to use Row/Column in the 2nd level positioner since it saves performance*  Have you measured how much savings do I have? What if it's a micro optimization and it's nothing relevant?